# Why won't my delete button work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some background in computer programming, but I am just getting into Javascript and jQuery. I have this code that will delete the element's grandparent but the function isn't running at all ("I am not seeing the "alert".) Can you help me find out what is wrong?

NOTE: There are multiple .trashbuttons and I just want the .trashbutton being clicked's grandparent getting deleted.

```
$("trashbutton").click(function() {
    this.parent().parent().remove();
})
```

EDIT: The answers I have been given are not working. I should also note that the `.trashbutton` is a `img`. If that helps.

Comment: `$("trashbutton")` you are using the wrong selector, that one tries to select an element named `trashbutton`, you want `.trashbutton`. Also `this` representing the actual DOM element and not a jQuery element

Comment: To target an ID you're missing `#` or a class `.` Example `$("#trashbutton").` for ID and for a class `$(".trashbutton").`

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in your selector, you forgot the `.` to select css classes.
And wrap `this` to `$()`.

try

```
$(".trashbutton").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggests you to keep reading on jQuery and javascript, especially [this documentation about jquery selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Your script function properly, except that `$("trashbutton")` refer to a `<trashbutton></trashbutton>` tag, that doesnt exist in your code ( i guess ). If you wanted to target an element class with that use `$(".trashbutton")` or `$("#trashbutton")` to target an element with this ID :)

Answer (score 2):

> Use `$(this)`...`this` will represent DOM element but you need jQuery wrapped element.

Try this:

```js
$(".trashbutton").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
})
```

**Edit:** As suggested in comments, make sure you have `$("trashbutton")` as valid selector..I assume you are dealing with classes hence it should be `$(".trashbutton")`

Comment: `this` isn't the issue. :p

Comment: Try it out mate...Console will show you: `Uncaught TypeError: this.parent is not a function`

Comment: I'm joking.... I'm shocked you didn't get it but the first issue to address is the selector.

Comment: @NewToJS, _I agree_ At first glance, `this.parent()` attracted me..It happens...;)

Comment: @NewToJS, Also note OP has mentioned about `..trashbuttons` in his post so it is also possible that he missed `.` while posting question...Or it could be the DOM structure which is making him fail...So many possibilities..Let him clarify those...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `#trashbutton` if it is an id or `.trashbutton` if it is a class. Also wrap `this` as `$(this)`.

```
$("#trashbutton").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
})
```

Comment: all your buttons are images doesn't necessarily mean all images are buttons